# Javascript not running on github, but runs on local machine

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I uploaded a project page on Github, but the page is not executing the javascript that works properly on a local machine.

Link to my github: 
https://lydiatest.github.io/

The sidebar menu and the header should carry the effect as of below:

https://codepen.io/mrReiha/pen/

All javascripts are located in the file index.js:

https://lydiatest.github.io/dats6401/js/index.js

```
 <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your script. It is with `jquery not getting loaded` due to url getting served from `http` instead of `https`.

Your script depends on jquery (which failed to download) and hence fails to run. You can check the console of your browser for further details.

Update http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js and it should work fine.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: I changed to javascript with https and the script is running now, but there is another problem.When I press the back to top bottom on lower right corner, there is a white space on the right, which does not appear on local machine. Do you know the cause of that? Or should I start a new post?

Comment: Did you update your code on above link? Not sure what might be the issue but on `https://lydiawawa.github.io/dats6401mid/` I can see some more errors on console. Can you try fixing those? One is http to https issue and other looks like a syntax error. Fixing those might solve your issue.

Comment: I fixed the errors, but the right side space on header still exists.

Comment: Better to start a new post as the issue is different from what you asked here. Also, post the screenshot of the UI highlighting the issue and the expected UI for better understanding of problem.